# Compatibility - SQL 2005 vs 2000

Tags: sql-server

I recently changed my compatibility mode of my sql server 2005 form 2000 to 2005. 
Is there a utility that can scan my sp and functions and tell me if I have any compatibility issues?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it works from inside sql 2005; but if you still have a sql 2000 server then MS have an [upgrade advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1470e86b-7e05-4322-a677-95ab44f12d75&displaylang=en) that will report on your code. If you don't scripting out all the objects and trying to run them back into a new database set as sql 2005 mode is a fairly good way to test the migration.

Depending on your application be careful just switching there are syntax differences and connection options that changed between 2000/5 beyond just stored procedure changes. If your application runs sql queries natively (not sp's) then the application may have compatibility issues beyond just the internal database code.

Comment: the app is vb/sql, most of what's going on are in sp or udf.
But I need some 05 functionality, hence the change of compatibility. 
I have an sql 2K server, but I don't know how to get this database on to it, since backup/restore won't working from 05 to 00.

Comment: To get back script out all your objects from management studio you could then run them back into a SQL 200 server; or try and create them into a sql 2005 database set to 2005 native mode. You can use dts to move your data into the right place.